# Cannot find ContractVerifierUtil class while trying to generate spring cloud contracts

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, maven-plugin, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to generate cloud contracts for my API but the build is failing as the generated test class cannot find the  below class from the dependency.

```
 Compilation failure--import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierUtil.*;

[ERROR] ContractVerifierTest.java:[18,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ContractVerifierUtil
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util
```

These are my dependencies in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.oai</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-request-validator-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Hoxton.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and my maven plugin configuration

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <baseClassForTests>
                    com.test.specValidation.ContractTest
                </baseClassForTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I've looked at the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216741/why-cant-my-class-find-contractverifierutil) but the version looks compatible as per spring cloud [docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

```
Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility
Release Train   Boot Version
Hoxton

2.2.x
```

I've tried with multiple versions but doesn't seem to work. Any guidance on what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please align the version of the plugin with the version of the contract dependency. You're using verifier in version 2.2.3.RELEASE however the plugin is in 2.1.1.RELEASE. They must be used in the same version.

Comment: I've tried using the same version plugin with verifier..Hasn't been much help

Comment: You have a version mismatch. That's a known issue when you import contract in 2 different versions. Plugin is in a new version, test compile classpath in an old one

Comment: Yeah I've tried version 2.2.3.RELEASE on both the plugin and the dependency but it did-not help resolving the problem. Thanks for the info though

Comment: Bump your release train too. Why do you set hoxton and cloud project versions manually. They will be resolved from the bom